# Joining 3 tables with mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three following tables.

```
table 1)
| ID_t1  |   name1   | price |
| ------ | --------- | ----- |
|   1    |    AAA    |  100  |
|   2    |    ABB    |  200  |
|   3    |    ACC    |  300  |

table 2)
| ID_t2  |   name2   |
| ------ | --------- |
|   1    |    pig    |
|   2    |    fog    |
|   3    |    dog    |

table 3)
| ID_t3  |   ID_t1   | ID_t2 | quantity |
| ------ | --------- | ----- | -------- |
|   1    |      1    |   1   |    50    |
|   2    |      2    |   1   |    60    |
|   3    |      2    |   2   |   100    |
|   4    |      2    |   3   |   110    |
|   5    |      3    |   2   |   150    |
|   6    |      3    |   3   |   140    |
```

So I have relation ibfk in table3 with column ID_t1, ID_t2.

I want to get result in mysql like this.

```
| ID_t3  |   name1   |  name2 | quantity |
| ------ | --------- | ------ | -------- |
|   1    |    AAA    |   pig  |    50    |
|   2    |    ABB    |   pig  |    60    |
|   3    |    ABB    |   fog  |   100    |
|   4    |    ABB    |   dog  |   110    |
|   5    |    ACC    |   fog  |   150    |
|   6    |    ACC    |   dog  |   140    |
```

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [edit] your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here what exactly you do for your query

```
SELECT 
table_3.ID_t3,
table_1.name1,
table_2.name2, 
table_3.quantity 
FROM table_3 
JOIN table_1 on table_3.ID_t1 = table_1.ID_t1 
JOIN table_2 ON table_3.ID_t2 = table_2.ID_t2
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Traditional inner joins will get the information you want.

For example:

```
select
  a.id_t3,
  b.name1,
  c.name2,
  a.quantity
from table3 a
join table1 b on b.id_t1 = a.id_t1
join table2 c on c.id_t2 = a.id_2
```

Comment: if i have duplicate value how can i get result